# SVG external use with vue not working, although while inspect element in chrome shows <use xlink:href > that it is correctly linked

Tags: svg, vue.js, flexbox, vuejs2, webpack-2

I followed http://joanmira.com/vuejs-first-impression-and-how-to-work-with-svgs/ to make icon component in vue (using webpack template). The Icon component is copy-paste from website. While Header.vue using the Icon component lives in the same directory and looks like following:

```
<template>
  <header class="main-header">
    /** ICON COMPONENT **/
    <icon width="100" height="100" :glyph="Logo"></icon>

    <div class="main-header-row">
      <div class="search-box">
        <input type="search" placeholder="search..."/>
        <button type="submit" class="searchButton" />
        <i class="search-icon"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="main-header-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">projecten</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">klanten</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">partners</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">tickets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">tools</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">meer</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="main-header-alerts-and-account">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">dean alert</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">meldingen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">account</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <icon width="500" height="200" :glyph= "Logo"></icon>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
  import Icon from './Icon'
  import Logo from '../assets/icons/logo.svg'

  export default {
    name: 'header',
    components: {
      Icon
    },
    data() {
      return { Logo }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .main-header-row,
  .main-header-nav > ul,
  .main-header-alerts-and-account > ul
  {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .main-header-row
  {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .main-header-nav > ul,
  .main-header-alerts-and-account > ul
  {
    list-style: none;
  }

  .main-header-nav > ul > li,
  .main-header-alerts-and-account > ul >li
  {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  .search-box
  {
    padding-top: 24px;
  }
</style>
```

When inspecting element(svg) on Chrome the  but I can not see in the browser!

Answer (score 0):

Used `<image :xlink:href="glyph" class="icon"/>` than `<use :xlink:href="glyph" class="icon"/>` in Icon component and it worked.